# How does one bind a PDO object for MySQL to a field of type TEXT?

Tags: php, pdo

I have tried using:

```
$rs->bindParam(':Synopsis125Line', $Synopsis125Line, PDO::PARAM_STR(4000));
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: `$rs->bindParam(':Synopsis125Line', $Synopsis125Line, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Well maybe 4000 is too big. Anyway, you could avoid it, this is not an obligation, you can use PDO::PARAM_STR without size

Comment: I'm having no problem bind other parameters and haven't had to specify size. I'm trying to migrate an app previously written in ASP that specified type adLongVarChar when binding this same data.

Comment: What goes wrong ? Do you have an error ?

Comment: I don't see any error (I almost never do), but I can tell that I don't reach the next line of code.

Comment: Surrounded it with a TRY (as I should have anyway) and I get the following error Error!: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: You have an error in your parameters (edit your question with the whole code: prepared statement & execute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax as stated above by Justin Luman is and [the php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

```
$rs->bindParam(':Synopsis125Line', $Synopsis125Line, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
```

If you're receiving an error here, it's likely not down to the syntax here, you're likely missing ':Synopsis125Line' from the query you're trying to prepare, or $Synopsis125Line is undefined or of incorrect type.

If you're trying to discover what the error is, try checking you're apache error log, run the script again with the following command running in a terminal window and it will output any errors:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log
```